# How to delete simulators below iPhone 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-simulator

I have a base model MBP with only 120gb space so I'm trying to free up as much as I can. After running a DaisyDisk scan it looks like I have 8.6gb of simulators.

I'd like to keep the simulators for iPhone 8 and above, and remove the simulators for earlier devices. Is there a way to do this? In DaisyDisk it doesn't specify which simulator is for which device, [it just looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxYrf.jpg).

Thanks for any help!

P.S - my personal phone is an iPhone 6+, I'm assuming deleting the iPhone 6 simulator won't cause any issues when I try to test apps on my device? As far as UI layout goes I can't see any issues doing the layout in an iPhone 8 storyboard then running it on my 6.

Comment: Wow, when I answered this question I didn't realize I had already answered it almost exactly 1 year ago.  I'm getting too old....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode,

1. Go to `Window -> Devices and Simulators` or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.
2. Click on `Simulators` at the top of the window.
3. On the left side you'll see the list of all the simulators installed on your system.  When you select one, you'll see the details of that simulator (OS version) on the top right.
4. Select the one you want to remove and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.  Confirm your request on the confirmation dialog.  You can only delete one at a time so it will take some time if you want to delete many of them.

Xcode will delete the simulator.  After this, I usually restart Xcode but I don't know if that's required to clear out the hard drive space.

Regarding your PS, there's no correlation between deleting an old simulator and your app running on a device.  The only thing you lose is seeing how the app would look on a device you don't personally own.  Only you can judge the value of that.