# How to download iPadOS 13 simulator for Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode, xcode-simulator, ipados

I have application in Xcode and I need to test it on **iPadOS 13**. But I can not find any hint how to set up iPadOS simulator. I can run iOS 13 on simulator but I want to try my app on iPadOS 13 simulator. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/341325/88313) for how to uninstall simulators.  Just do almost the same thing to install new simulators.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked that answer but I could not find iPadOS simulator. There is only iOS simulator.

Comment: I can run iOS 13 on iPad simulator but that is not iPadOS. I want to run iPadOS 13 on iPad simulator.

Comment: How do you determine the difference of "iOS13 on iPad" and "iPadOS 13"? Also, which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're looking but the iPad simulators are are listed there.  All iPhone and iPad simulators are listed under the 'iOS' title.  When you click on an iPad simulator you should see the version as 13.3.  Do you have any iPad simulators installed already?

Comment: I don't know why fsb still can't see it. IpadOS already existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xcode 11.3 supports developing apps for iOS 13.3, iPadOS 13.3, tvOS 13.3, watchOS 6.1, and macOS Catalina 10.15.2.

So make sure you have Xcode 11.3, which is available for

> a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.4 or later.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_3_release_notes?language=objc

Also, make a simulator if not already there in Window menu →  Devices and Simulators window. Choose device and it should show available iOS/iPadOS. If not present, hit "Download more simulator runtimes" and see if it shows up in the list.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devf225e58da
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deva7379ae35

Comment: On Xcode 11.4 and macOS 10.15.5 - iPadOS is not listed in the downloadable runtimes. :(

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still finding it difficult, when you download simulator, from **Devices and Simulators** option, you select an iOS version (say iOS 14.4). Once the download is finished and installed, you will have all the iPhone device simulators and iPad device simulators of OS version 14.4 available to be used as target device.

There isn't anything specific for iPad OS.